# Merge dfs but avoid duplication of columns and maintain the order in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

All the dfs have a key col "id".
pd.merge is not a viable option even with the suffix option.
There are over 40k cols in each of the dfs so column binding and deleting later (suffix_x) is not an option. Exactly 50k (common) rows in each of the dfs identified by "id" col.

Minimal example with two common cols:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'col1': [123, 121, 111],
  'col2': [456, 454, 444],
  'col3': [786, 787, 777],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'col1': [123, 121, 111],
  'col2': [456, 454, 444],
  'col4': [11, 44, 77],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'col1': [123, 121, 111],
  'col2': [456, 454, 444],
  'col5': [1786, 1787, 1777],
})
```

Final answer:

```
finaldf = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'col1': [123, 121, 111],
  'col2': [456, 454, 444],
  'col3': [786, 787, 777],
  'col4': [11, 44, 77],
  'col5': [1786, 1787, 1777], 
})
```

Comment: Are the indices already aligned? And is the overlapping data identical?

Comment: Indices are aligned and the overlapping cols are identical.

Comment: I don't think your example is reproducible. Your example does not produce suffix(_x, _y) even if you use merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory is limiting and the dataframes are already aligned, you could try to set up the output and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) it:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
cols = reduce(lambda a,b: a.union(b, sort=False),
              (x.columns for x in dfs))

out = pd.DataFrame(index=dfs[0].index,
                   columns=cols)
for x in dfs:
    out.update(x)
```

Variant for the last step:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(dfs[0],
                   columns=cols)
for x in dfs[1:]:
    out.update(x)
```

Output:

```
  id col1 col2 col3 col4  col5
0  a  123  456  786   11  1786
1  b  121  454  787   44  1787
2  c  111  444  777   77  1777
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
    import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col1': [123, 121, 111],
    'col2': [456, 454, 444],
    'col3': [786, 787, 777],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col1': [123, 121, 111],
    'col2': [456, 454, 444],
    'col4': [11, 44, 77],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col1': [123, 121, 111],
    'col2': [456, 454, 444],
    'col5': [1786, 1787, 1777],
})

# Merge df1 and df2 on 'id', then merge the result with df3 on 'id'
final_df = df1.set_index('id').combine_first(df2.set_index('id')).combine_first(df3.set_index('id')).reset_index()
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
  id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  a   123   456   786    11  1786
1  b   121   454   787    44  1787
2  c   111   444   777    77  1777
```

Comment: Good solution but it kills the kernel because of ram size. Need something which will avoid the creation of those duplicate (_x) cols.